# Extended Request class's attributes are empty - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

I've created an own Request called ValidateSecretRequest for the google 2fa. But I only get empty attributes.

As additional information: I followed a tutorial from https://www.sitepoint.com/2fa-in-laravel-with-google-authenticator-get-secure/

After the authenticate() method the LoginController executes the postValidateToken() method. For testing I only implemented the request output.

**LoginController**

```
public function postValidateToken(ValidateSecretRequest $request) {
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($request); echo '</pre>';
}
```

**Request class**

Firstly I supposed that there was a mistake with the extened Request? Actually it should be right in this way?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Cache;
use Crypt;
use Google2FA;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidatonFactory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ValidateSecretRequest extends Request {
   /**
    *
    * @var \App\User
    */
   private $user;
   public $totp;

   /**
    * Create a new FormRequest instance.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Validation\Factory $factory
    * @return void
    */
   public function __construct(ValidatonFactory $factory) {
      $factory->extend(
         'valid_token',
         function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $secret = Crypt::decrypt($this->user->google2fa_secret);

            return Google2FA::verifyKey($secret, $value);
         },
         'Not a valid token'
      );

      $factory->extend(
         'used_token',
         function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $key = $this->user->id . ':' . $value;

            return !Cache::has($key);
         },
         'Cannot reuse token'
      );
   }

   /**
    * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
    *
    * @return bool
    */
   public function authorize() {
      try {
         $this->user = User::findOrFail(
            session('2fa:user:id')
         );
      } catch (Exception $exc) {
         return false;
      }

      return true;
   }

   /**
    * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function rules() {
      return [
         'totp' => 'bail|required|digits:6|valid_token|used_token',
      ];
   }
}
```

But the function postValidateToken() returns an empty array.

```
App\Http\Requests\ValidateSecretRequest Object
(
    [user:App\Http\Requests\ValidateSecretRequest:private] => 
    [totp] => 
    [json:protected] => 
    [convertedFiles:protected] => 
    [userResolver:protected] => 
    [routeResolver:protected] => 
    [attributes] => 
    [request] => 
    [query] => 
    [server] => 
    ...
    [session:protected] => 
    [locale:protected] => 
    [defaultLocale:protected] => en
    [isHostValid:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request:private] => 1
    [isForwardedValid:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request:private] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

You have to use FormRequest not Request

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
```